# Isolated IAM roles for multiple long running applications on the same server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 server with multiple applications hosted on it. I currently have to live with this setup for now (I can't put each app on its own server).

I don't want to use a single system wide set of creds for ALL the apps running on the server.

Each app should only have access to only the stuff it needs. This is important for troubleshooting/debugging and isolating the application's access. I'm trying to figure out how this can be done.

I could give the EC2 instance role access to assume application specific roles. So the applications, on initialization, would have access to assume a role just for their use. This *seems* like the right way to go but these are very long running applications. Even if I set the token expiration very high it will need to be refreshed. Do the STS clients for Java and .net support a way to auto-refresh? Will I have to implement this logic myself somehow? Like have the app check the token isn't expired before every single AWS API call? I don't want to have to implement this in code.

I don't like it, but I could also create IAM users for all the applications and store their credentials in parameter store or the secret manager. The EC2 role would have access to read those secrets and when the apps start they pull down a secret with their IAM users keys and use those in their session. They would not have to use sts or implement refresh logic but I'm using static access keys which I do not like - maybe the secret manager thing can rotate the IAM keys for me?

Comment: When you say "these are very long running applications", do you mean the applications have long running processes? Can you give an example of why you think this causes a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know for the AWS SDK for .NET it is possible to have the SDK manage refreshing credentials for you. Below is a small snippet of code to create an `AWSCredentials` object that under the covers will get credentials by assuming a role using the instance profile credentials. The `AssumeRoleAWSCredentials` object will automatically refresh before the credentials are expired.

```
using Amazon.Runtime;

namespace AssumeRoleCredsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var roleArn = "your-application-role-arn-here";
            var instanceProfileCredentials = FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials();

            var assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleAWSCredentials(instanceProfileCredentials, roleArn, "Application1SessionName");
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the AWS SDK for Java has very similar feature. Taking a quick look at the JavaDocs for the AWS SDK for Java I would look at the `com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` class.

Comment: this is interesting, how does it do that? So I would make assumeRoleCredentials like a global object my application uses for making all API calls? If so how does it refresh if I only instantiate it once? Or would that be a static method I call each time before each API call?

Comment: When you create your service clients for example the s3 client you would pass in the assumeRoleCredentials instance into the client. Something like `var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(assumeRoleCredentials);` Under the covers the AssumeRoleAWSCredentials object maintains state about the credentials and will refresh them overtime before the credentials are expired. You should reuse the instance of assumeRoleCredentials for each service client you create.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! So AssumeRoleAWSCredentials class must check its current expiration time before each call right? There isn't any performance impact to that is there? Like say a web app that needs to make 1000s of requests to various AWS services?

Comment: It will make one additional call to Amazon Security Token Service (STS) about once an hour per instance of AssumeRoleAWSCredentials which is why I recommend reusing the same instance of AssumeRoleAWSCredentials to avoid excessive calls to (STS).

I also recommend setting the environment variable AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS to "regional" if you are using a different region then us-east-1. That way your app will use the STS endpoint in the region your application is running in instead of going to us-east-1. That is a newish feature we added to the SDK so be sure to you are using the latest SDK.